# How to do the whole div scroll on scroll event?

Tags: html, fullpage.js

So, the question is pretty basic but I couldn't find an example snippet to start with.

Idea is to have multiple div with full-screen height and upon scroll, the whole of the div scrolls making the user think that they are on same position and content is coming on same position. [ kinda-ish]

I have an example website where such scrolling behaviour is done. [here](https://ifoundwhatyoulost.com/)

Just a reference will help me start.

Thanks

Comment: this is full page js, please checkout the website
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1

Comment: keep coding bro